# Обьединение файлов Git

Tags: git, контроль-версий, git-merge

Добрый день, есть данные полученные из Git, я вношу правки и работаю над этим проектом, соответственно делаю коммиты в свой репазитарий. Далее мне присылают архив файлов с небольшими изменениями. Но он полный тоесть такой же как и был у меня изначально и в нем есть файлы и с правками и без. Как мне смержить эти файлы без потери моих изменений, понятно что просто замена не подходит. Репазитарии разные, компании тоже. Понятно что могли бы прислать только измененные файлы или патч, или просто изменения. но формат только такой. У кого какие есть предложения?

Comment: Кто знает как сделать мердж с помошью Git и дополнительных веток?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я эту задачу решаю так:

1. Нахожу в истории своего репозитория коммит, который был общий для моей и их копии, или последний коммит, в котором я с ними сверялся (будет создан на шаге 4).
2. Создаю на этом коммите новую ветку или нахожу оставленную с прошлого раза, и переключаюсь в нее.
3. Удаляю файловым менеджером все файлы, и копирую присланные.
4. Делаю commit с комментарием "правки, присланные %дата%".
5. Переключаюсь в свою ветку или свой master, и делаю merge с новой веткой.
6. Если такая синхронизация делается редко, то новую ветку можно удалить, если часто - оставить для следующей синхронизации.

Comment: Так будут же конфликты, у меня, при чем очень много, файлов на 400 мб. Если я правильно понял надо сделать вторую ветку только с их изменениями и просто смержить, а как быть с файлами которые я правлю ? Они не затруться(изменения?)

Comment: @ИльгамКаримов, вы должны сделать ветку на коммите ДО ваших правок. Конфликты будут, безусловно, но при merge вы будете видеть и свои правки и их и общий оригинал. Ваши правки, находящиеся в другой ветке, не затрутся. В случае проблем всегда можно отменить merge и сделать повторно.

Comment: Спасибо, это то что нужно)

Answer (score 1):

У меня возникает подобная задача и решаю ее следующим образом. У меня есть установленный [meld](http://meldmerge.org/). Он позволяет сравнить два каталога и аккуратно перетаскивать изменения. После того, как изменения перенесены - можно спокойно закомитить.  Естественно, вместо meld можно использовать любую другую утилиту для сравнения.

Comment: Есть ли подобная программа для Linux?

Comment: Да. Meld есть под Линукс (есть в репах).